# Docker remove all images permission denied

Tags: docker

When I want to delete all images with the command

```
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

I've got

```
WARNING: Error loading config file:stat /home/developer/.docker/config.json: permission denied
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
docker: "rmi" requires a minimum of 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
```

But delete image for image with command

```
sudo docker rmi c4bea91afef3
```

Then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` only affects `docker rmi`.  You need to specify it again for `docker images`:

```
sudo docker rmi -f $(sudo docker images -q)
```